# Referring To MessageBox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a program that kids can use to code from within my application instead of a console-based approach

So I have a lesson that teaches them about message boxes, they are given a sample line of code and what it creates and are told to create their own by entering code into a textbox to create their own that says "Hey Dude!", the problem is, I'm having trouble getting the system to check if what they entered was correct or not... eg:

```
Private Sub btnShowMsgBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowMsgBox.Click
        If txtUserInput.Text = MessageBox.Show("I can code!") Then
            MessageBox.Show("I can code!")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("That's not quite right, try again!")
        End If
```

I've tried adding " " around the relevent code on the first line of the if statement but no joy, as well as trying a variable approach

So basically the problem is the program is getting confused and doesn't understand why I'm checking to see if code for a message box is present, the syntax of the messagebox code doesn't fit well either

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I would get this working? The logic is so straightforward but it's driving me nuts!

Thanks a million in advance

Comment: `If txtUserInput.Text = ("I can code!") ...` but it wIlL Be cASe sensITivE

Comment: `MessageBox.Show` returns a DialogResult, so comparing it to a string won't work.

Comment: Since this is for kids in school ... please correct your failure message to "That's not quite right. Try again!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want the code to look more like...

```
Private Sub btnShowMsgBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowMsgBox.Click
    If txtUserInput.Text = "MessageBox.Show(""I can code!"")" Then
        MessageBox.Show("I can code!")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("That's not quite right, try again!")
    End If
```

The double quotes will return as single quotes within the string between the single quotes.

Comment: That works, thanks a million!

The logic of it was quite simple, but I didn't think of using double quotes, I suppose its such a unique and unused element of functionality that it was difficult for me to comprehend, thanks again! Enjoy your weekend

Comment: @user2962071 = If you need a case insensitive method, then you can use String.Equals:  `If String.Equals(txtUserInput.Text, "MessageBox.Show(""I can code!"")", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then`

Comment: For teaching purposes though it would probably be best to conform to the case sensitive nature of VB.NET ... teaching bad habits at the start is never a good idea.